# D3: the exit().remove() not working on changing the dropdown value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I have two similar bar charts on a single webpage and a dropdown having month to change the bar chart according to the value of month. I have only one csv file containing all the values. Now. I am trying to change the bar chart dataset according to the value of dropdown but the bar chart is changing the dataset value but the function exit().remove() is not working properly, the charts gets appended on each other.

My code is as follow:

```
 function updateLegend(dataset)
{

var tip1=d3.tip()
        .attr("class","tooltip")
        .offset([-10,0])
        .html(function(d){
        return "<strong>Application Name : </strong><span  style='color:blue'>"+d.AppName+"</span> <br> <strong> Support Cost :</strong> <span style='color:blue'>"+d.Supportcost+"</span>";
        });

 var tip2=d3.tip()
        .attr("class","tooltip")
        .offset([-10,0])
        .html(function(d){
        return "<strong>Application Name : </strong><span style='color:blue'>"+d.AppName+"</span> <br> <strong> Support Hours :</strong> <span style='color:blue'>"+d.Supporthrs+"</span>";
        });    
   x.domain(dataset.map(function(d){return d.AppID;}));
   y0.domain([0,d3.max(dataset,function(d){return d.Supportcost;})]);

 chart1.append("g")
     .attr("class","x axis")
     .attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")")
     .call(xAxis)
     .selectAll("text")
     .style("text-anchor","end")
     .attr("dx","-0.8em")
     .attr("dy","-.5em")
     .attr("transform","rotate(-90)");

     chart1.call(tip1);
  bars1=chart1.selectAll(".bar").data(dataset);

  bars1.enter()
     .append("rect")
    .attr("class","bar1")
    .attr("x",function(d){return x(d.AppID);})
    .attr("y",function(d){return y0(d.Supportcost);})
    .attr("width",x.rangeBand())
       .attr("height",function(d,i,j) { return height - y0(d.Supportcost);       })
       .on("mouseover",tip1.show)
       .on("mouseout",tip1.hide); 


  x.domain(dataset.map(function(d){return d.AppID;}));
  y0.domain([0,d3.max(dataset,function(d){return d.Supporthrs;})]);



 chart2.call(tip2);
 bars2=chart2.selectAll(".bar").data(dataset);

 bars2.enter()
      .append("rect")
    .attr("class","bar2")
    .attr("x",function(d){return x(d.AppID);})
    .attr("y",function(d){return y0(d.Supporthrs);})
    .attr("width",x.rangeBand())
       .attr("height",function(d,i,j) { return height - y0(d.Supporthrs); })
         .on("mouseover",tip2.show)
       .on("mouseout",tip2.hide); 

  bars1.exit().remove();
  bars2.exit().remove();
  }
```

My Full source code is as follows:-
http://plnkr.co/edit/ibu4H5u5lzuxTFYIqSaF

[The bar chart appends like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLcjF.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 problems:

1. You selectAll against a class (".bar") which you then don't use as the class for the appended elements (you use "bar1"), so it will never find any .bar instances to exit.
2. Once that's fixed you need a data function that identifies each data point in your set uniquely - I've went for appid and month and year - otherwise you will then never get any new elements entrying after the first month selected. They will sit in the update selection which you don't use here (which is the selection with neither .exit() or .enter() added as a qualifier)

Do the below for bars1 and then similar for bars2 (using .bar2 as the class):

```
bars1=chart1.selectAll(".bar1").data(dataset, function(d) {
      return d.AppID+d.Month+d.Year;
    });

    bars1.enter()
         .append("rect")
        .attr("class","bar1")
// your code continues...
```

Comment: It also occurs that a more d3 way of doing things would be to have just function(d) { return d.AppID; } as the data key and then set in a update selection all the x,y,width,height attributes you currently set using the .enter() selection. This opens the door to doing nice transitions, but for the time being my answer does solve your immediate problem.

Comment: How Should I change the values of x axis and y axis accordingly...??

Comment: y0.domain([0,d3.max(dataset,function(d){return +d.Supportcost;})]);

put plus signs in front of the d., it seems to be interpreting them as strings in the above function otherwise.
Then recall each axis as so (you have the further difficulty that you're re-using the same axis and scale for each chart, you'll need one for each)

chart1.select("g.y").call(yAxisLeft);